# Does "irgendweshalb" exist?

Tags: meaning

There are 2 used expressions to express "for some unknown reason" I know of:

> Wieso/weshalb/warum auch immer, aus irgendeinem Grund

And several slight variations of those.

However, there seems to be the need for *one* word which expresses the same. From 2010 to 2023, I can find various examples on social media services online, at least.
There seems to be a natural need for native speakers to put focus on the actor instead of the action, which **irgendwie** does not accomplish.

> Irgendwie habe ich verschlafen. (Weil der Wecker nicht klingelte)
> Irgendweshalb habe ich verschlafen. (Wegen des Weckers)

Another example from a Twitter posting I found through the search:

> *Eure Bubble denkt irgendweshalb, dass die CDU die besseren Konzepte hat.*  ([source](https://twitter.com/mauerbrand/status/1415099166049677317))

What would be the alternative phrasing?

> Eure Bubble denkt *aus irgendeinem Grund*, dass...
> Eure Bubble denkt *wieso auch immer*, dass...

Clunky! Understandably, the author came up with a quicker way to express the same.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be question, rather an appeal to add a word that either doesn't exist or only exists informally. You don't need permission to start using it yourself, and if you did this isn't where you'd ask for it. However, I wouldn't use it any any kind of formal situation.

Answer (score 3):

Quote:

> However, there seems to be the need for one word which expresses the same.

What makes you think that? I am a native German speaker. I live in Austria, a country where people speak German to each other in everyday life, and I have spoken this language every single day for more than half a century.
But I have never felt the need to use a single word in place of "aus irgendeinem Grund" or similar multi-word-expressions. Nor do I feel that any of the many native German speakers I know have ever had this need.

---

In German you have these 12 *irgend*-words:

- **irgendein**

  > Nimm irgendein Messer und schneide damit das Brot.

  There are also inflected forms. (*»Nimm doch einfach irgendeines.« »Kennt den irgendeiner von euch?«*)
- **irgendeinmal**

  > Besuchen Sie uns doch irgendeinmal in unserem Stammhaus.
- **irgendetwas**

  > Ich möchte noch irgendetwas essen bevor ich gehe.
- **irgendjemand**

  > Irgendjemand muss die Verantwortung übernehmen.

  There are also inflected forms. (*»Wehe, du erzählst das irgendjemandem!«*)
- **irgendwann**

  > Irgendwann wird es zu spät sein.
- **irgendwas**

  > Ist irgendwas passiert?
- **irgendwelche**

  > Georg hat einfach irgendwelche Tapeten gekauft.

  There are also inflected forms. (*»Ich werde das doch nicht wegen irgendwelcher dahergelaufener Tussis einfach so ändern!«*)
- **irgendwer**

  > Irgendwer hat die Milch ausgetrunken.

  There are also inflected forms. (*»Das muss doch irgendwem gehören.« »Siehst du irgendwen?«*)
- **irgendwie**

  > Das ist irgendwie seltsam.
- **irgendwo**

  > Der zweite Schuh muss doch irgendwo sein!
- **irgendwoher**

  > Er muss ja von irgendwoher gekommen sein.
- **irgendwohin**

  > Ich haue ab, irgendwohin, wo mich keiner findet.

But German has also these 37 so called [W-Wörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-Wort) ("W words") which are adverbs and pronouns that are used in questions:

> wann, warum, was, welche, welchem, welchen, welcher, welches, wem, wen, wer, weshalb, wessen, weswegen, wie, wieso, wieweit, wo, wobei, wodurch, wofür, wogegen, woher, wohin, wohinter, womit, woneben, woran, worauf, woraus, worin, worum, worunter, worüber, wovon, wovor, wozu

But only some of them exist also inside of compounds with *irgend*, while the most of them can't be combined with *irgend.*

---

But of course German is not a dead language. It is a living language, and that means it is constantly changing. The same mechanism that brought us words like *irgendwie, irgendwo, irgendwann* in the past could bring us words like *irgenwoneben, irgendwarum* or also *irgendweswegen* in the future.

But in the present, in the year 2023, these words are either not used at all or are used with such a low frequency that the majority of native German speakers consider them to be wrong. And so do the authors of all dictionaries that I consulted when I did the research for this answer.

It's true, that Google finds 417 webpages (mainly on social media sites) that contain the word *»irgendweshalb«.* But you also find 22000 webpages containing *»Endgeld«* and even more than 10 million webpages that contain the word *»garnicht«.* Both words are wrong (correct are *»[Entgelt](https://nachgeholfen.de/deutsch/schreiben/endgeld-oder-entgelt/)«* and *»[gar nicht](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/garnicht.shtml)«*), and there is no doubt about that.

You can find almost every wrong or nonexistent word on internet, but that does not mean that it's part of the standard language. It even doesn't mean, that it's part of colloquial speech or some regional dialect. Even finding more entries than of an existing word doesn't really mean that the word that is used with a higher frequency is correct (*»garnicht«*: wrong, but more than 10 million pages on Google, but the existing and correct word *»Milchaufschäumer«* is found on just 3 million webpages). But the fact that only 417 pages were found is strong evidence that more than 99.9999% of all native speakers think this word is wrong.

Comment: You can find many uses of "irgendweshalb" on social media platforms if you utilize the advanced search function or use regular searches. People seem to come up with it every now and then. That's why I assume that there is a natural need for it. 
But thank you for your detailed list, it will be most likely be helpful for many people after me reading your answer as well.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: I added a section of 4 paragraphs to the end of my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Why does not using a word imply thinking it is "wrong"?

Comment: Fascinating. While all the other "irgend-" words and I actually do occasionally use "irgendwarum" myself, I had never heard of "irgendeinmal" and had to check what it means. It's not built based on a question word like the other "irgend-" words and I would have assumed it's a neologism just as much as "irgendwarum" without hesitation. Maybe that one is particularly regional?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The word "irgendeinmal" is used with significant frequency in written German only in Switzerland according to https://www.dwds.de/wb/irgendeinmal#map-2 . But I can add, that is it also used in eastern parts of Austria in spoken German. Mainly in dialects, but also in colloquial speech.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: It seems to be like it is a shortened version of "irgendwann einmal". In any case, it stands out a bit from the others.

Comment: »Irgendeinmal« in newspapers: Switzerland: [Source 1](https://www.jungfrauzeitung.ch/artikel/209092/), [Source 2](https://www.grenchnertagblatt.ch/solothurn/grenchen/lengnau-irgendeinmal-kann-es-sein-dass-wir-im-alltag-hilfe-benoetigen-seniorennetzwerk-lengnau-informierte-ld.2511724), [Source 3](https://www.nzz.ch/sport/wie-der-einstige-st-pauli-trainer-schultz-in-basel-bestehen-will-ld.1743426). Austria: [Source 1](https://www.kleinezeitung.at/kaernten/stveit/6153731/Stille-Helden_Sie-sagt-der-Lebensmittelverschwendung-den-Kampf-an)

Answer (score 2):

While **irgendwie** lacks the focus on cause and effect, I would prefer it in the given examples. It is still colloquial and next formal phrase you already mentioned is:

> aus irgendeinem Grund

The benefit to cram it into one strange-sounding word is not obvious to me.

Comment: Exactly as you say: It is not satisfying to use "irgendwie". But I guess that's just how it has to be then. The benefit I see is the same as using ellipsis: expressing the same with less while not losing anything. I believe this is called "Sprachökonomie", but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't exist, neither do "irgendwarum" or "irgendwieso". This isn't very different from English where "somehow" and "somewhere" exist but I do not think I have ever seen "somewhy".

Natural languages are not 100% consistent in everything or even most things. If you want that, you need to learn a constructed language like Esperanto where "ial" is a perfectly normal word. There is no doubt that it would be a useful addition in both German and English; there are many times one needs to say "for some reason"/"aus irgendeinem Grund". This doesn't change the fact that "irgendweshalb" isn't a word widely used by real native speakers. You can sometimes say "irgendwie" which overlaps in meaning.